# Tables in Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am very new to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and SQL in general. I have a very trivial question.
I just created my first database and in it I created a table called `programmer`. In the object explorer under my database I can see my table `programmer`. I tried to create a second table called `customer` just to get the hang of SQL but the `customer` table does not show up under my database name only the table `programmer` is displayed.

My question is where is the second table in the object explorer?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right click tables and choose refresh. See it now?

Comment: Thank you for the comments it showed up after I refreshed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to refresh the Object Explorer tree.

Either:

- Collapse and expand the Tables folder, or
- Right click the Tables folder and click Refresh

Answer (score 0):

You might have created the table in a different database.